# Poor performance with Intel Threading Building Blocks using task_group (new user)

Tags: c++, tbb

I recently got interested in Intel Threading Building Blocks. I would like to make use of the `tbb::task_group` class to manage a thread pool.

My first attempt was to build a test where a copy a vector in another: I create nth tasks each taking care of copying a continuous slice of the vector.

However, performances decreases with the number of threads. I have the same results with another thread pool implementation. With TBB 2018 Update 5, gcc 6.3 on debian strecth on an 8 i7 core box, I get the following figures to copy a vector of 1'000'000 of elements:

nth  real      user

1    0.808s 0.807s

2    1.068s 2.105s

4    1.109s 4.282s

May be some of you would me help understanding the issue. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include "tbb/task_group.h"
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"

namespace mgis{
  using real = double;
  using size_type = size_t;
}

void my_copy(std::vector<mgis::real>& d,
         const std::vector<mgis::real>& s,
         const mgis::size_type b,
         const mgis::size_type e){
  const auto pb = s.begin()+b;
  const auto pe = s.begin()+e;
  const auto po = d.begin()+b;
  std::copy(pb,pe,po);
}

int main(const int argc, const char* const* argv) {
  using namespace mgis;
  if (argc != 3) {
    std::cerr << "invalid number of arguments\n";
    std::exit(-1);
  }
  const auto ng = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  const auto nth = std::stoi(argv[2]);
  tbb::task_scheduler_init init(nth);
  tbb::task_group g;
  std::vector<real> v(ng,0);
  std::vector<real> v2(ng);
  for(auto i =0; i!=2000;++i){
    const auto d = ng / nth;
    const auto r = ng % nth;
    size_type b = 0;
    for (size_type i = 0; i != r; ++i) {
      g.run([&v2, &v, b, d] { my_copy(v2, v, b, b + d + 1); });
      b += d+1;
    }
    for (size_type i = r; i != nth; ++i) {
      g.run([&v2, &v, b, d] { my_copy(v2, v, b, b + d); });
      b += d ;
    }
    g.wait();
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. such a short benchmark does not make sense as TBB needs to create threads and get them started, it does not happen immediately on the first call to TBB since it is lazy asynchronous process. Though, your user times suggest that threads are up and running but probably don't have work to do.
2. memcopy is bad for scalability study because it does not scale beyond the number of memory controllers/channels. So, it doesn't matter if you have 4 CPUs or 24, it's unlikely you can get more than x4 speedup even for good hardware. Yours might have less channels.
3. instead of manually splitting the range, use `tbb::parallel_for`, you don't need `task_group` there. Moreover, invoking tasks one by one has linear complexity, `parallel_for` has logarithmic complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My questions has to be made clearer. For clarification, I am not really interested by this memcopy-like tests but with more complex operations where tasks based parallelism is far better suited. However, the same test with openmp (simple raw #pragram parallel for instructions) **does** show a gain in performance as the number of threads increases (and as far as I know, OpenMP also has to starts its pool of threads). Even though the scalability is bad, my point is that in the performances decreases with TBB has the number of threads increases.

Comment: I'll make the same tests with `parallel_for` as you suggested, however, as I said in the previous comment, `parallel_for` will not be suitable for my real needs.

Comment: parallel_for works almost always. even if you don't have a finite number of elements, even if their number is not easily discoverable in constant time but well expressed via divisible range. e.g. a binary tree, then parallel_for works for that very well. If you don't want to write a custom range class, with `paralle_do`, you can add additional items later https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_do_func.html